# Why it's wrong to use L'Hôpital method twice?

Tags: calculus

We have,
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{g(x)}{x},&if\ x\not=0\\
0,&if\ x=0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
given $g(0) = {g}'(0) = 0$, ${g}''(0) = 3$, try to solve ${f}'(0)$
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}{x^2}
$$
From L'Hôpital method, we know
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{{g}'(x)}{2x}
$$
here is my question: why it's wrong to use L'Hôpital again to obtain the following?
$$
{f}'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{{g}''(x)}{2}=3/2
$$
my text book says the right way to do this is
$$
f'(0)=\frac 1 2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g'(x)-g'(0)}{x-0}=\frac {g''(0)} 2=3/2
$$

Comment: Do they really use the define article 'the' in "the right way"?

Answer (score 5):

This answer was wrong. As explained by Paramanand Singh in comments, the conditions for applying L'Hôpital's rule are not given because we don't know whether $g'$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $0$, so the textbook is right.

---

There's nothing wrong with applying L'Hôpital twice (though preferably it should be spelled the same way both times ;-). The answer in the book makes use of the fact that what you have is by definition (proportional to) the second derivative at $0$, but your approach is more generally applicable.

Comment: I wouldn't really say the approach is "better" than the one in the book. I think using l'Hôpital's rule to compute $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)/x$ (with $f(0) = 0$) when it's already the definition of the derivative shows that one doesn't really understand what's going on and is just applying rules blindly...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Convinced :-) I edited the answer accordingly. OK now?

Comment: OK. I thought the double hopital way was right. But my text book says specifically that it's wrong...

Comment: Well, Wikipedia explicitly states that l'Hôpital can be applied recursively which, in my view, is logical: Just imagine you have a function $h(x)$ which happens to be the same as $g'(x)$...

Comment: @WinterYoung: For me to say more about that, you'd have to quote the passage in the text book verbatim (or link to). Either the text book is wrong, or you're misunderstanding and misquoting it. Both are known to happen frequently :-)

Comment: There's nothing to quote. It's a Chinese text book to ask the readers to think about why it's wrong to use L'Hopital method twice directly. Simple as that, nothing more. I think I will close this topic. Maybe there's really nothing special, the author could be wrong.

Comment: @WinterYoung: Well that's weird -- if it was even meant to illustrate the wrongness, one might have expected that they'd choose an example where the allegedly wrong method yields a wrong result. With respect to "closing this topic": The normal procedure would be to either accept an answer or point out what you're missing in it. Posts are meant to remain for others to profit from, so they should usually not be deleted.

Comment: @WinterYoung: your Chinese textbook is correct. The second use of L'Hospital's Rule would require that $g''(x) $ exist in neighborhood of $0$ and the limit of $g''(x) $ also exists. None of this is given here. You only know that $g''(0)=3$.

Comment: @WinterYoung: for a counter-example consider $g(x) =\int_{0}^{x}t^2\sin(1/t)\,dt+(3/2)x^2$ then $g(0)=g'(0)=0,g''(0)=3$,but limit of $g''(x) $ as $x\to 0$ does not exist.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you! that's clear.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks for pointing out the error! I've corrected the answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: @WinterYoung: My apologies for the error. I'm sorry it took so long to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the rule for indeterminate form applies to the original equation. If the first prime is no longer indeterminate, then it would be pointless to try for the double prime as the problem no longer fits within the definition's requirements for use.